# Trying to decrypt message but gettingTypeError: can't concat bytes to str

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql

I am trying to decrypt the encrypted data which is stored in database but getting type error message:
TypeError: can't concat bytes to str
This is my code:

```
    password = b'password shared between Alice and Bob'
    message = b"This is a message for Bob's eyes only"
    kdf = pwhash.argon2i.kdf
    salt = utils.random(pwhash.argon2i.SALTBYTES)
    ops = pwhash.argon2i.OPSLIMIT_SENSITIVE
    mem = pwhash.argon2i.MEMLIMIT_SENSITIVE

    key = kdf(secret.SecretBox.KEY_SIZE, password, salt,opslimit=ops, memlimit=mem)
    box = secret.SecretBox(key)
    nonce = utils.random(secret.SecretBox.NONCE_SIZE)
    encrypted = box.encrypt(message, nonce)

    sql = "INSERT INTO encrypted (datastored) VALUES (%s);"
    cur.execute(sql,(str(encrypted),))
    conn.commit()


    sql = "SELECT  datastored from  encrypted"
    cur.execute(sql)
    row_value = cur.fetchone()[0]

    key_for_decryption = kdf(secret.SecretBox.KEY_SIZE, password,salt, opslimit=ops, memlimit=mem)
    decryption_box = secret.SecretBox(key_for_decryption)
    received = decryption_box.decrypt(row_value)
```

Comment: On which line does your error relate to? Try taking the SQL our of the equation, to see whether your encrypt/decrypt pare of calls work cleanly on the same data.

Comment: i am getting error at the last line... and if  i am working without sql the same code is working perfectly

Comment: That suggests your underlying error is in transport, storage or retrieval of the data. What type of database server are you using? Can you show us your database schema (or relevant part). Be aware that encrypted data is binary byte streams, so won't store meaningfully in a string type field.

Comment: i am using postgresql... and field type for this encrypted data is varchar

Answer (score 0):

For binary data, such as encrypted or compressed data, it is necessary to store it in a binary field, such as the `bytea` type in Postgres.

Storing it has in a `varchar` field will mean that some bytes, particularly with a zero value will cause loss of data.

Comment: after changing the type of field still its not working

Comment: Can you compare the value that you store, with the value that you retrieve. Obviously, they should be identical.

Comment: offcourse they are identically, i am just stuck in the last part i.e decrypting part